How can I recover deleted AWS Lambda code?
I've overwrote an AWS Lambda by accidented and replaced by uploading a zip file containing code for other Lambda function.
Is there any way to recover the previous code?
Moving forward - what's the best practice for deploying Lambda functions code?

You do have a local repository where you still have the original code, no? Lambda wasn't the only place you had that code, right? — If no… well, let this be a lesson.

And, well, have you looked in the Versions tab? Do you have old versions there?

Choose tooling such as CDK, AWS SAM or Serverless Framework, revision-control your code and infrastructure automation (e.g. in GitHub), and use CI/CD to deploy it.

Store your code in Github.

If you have been publishing versions, you can go to the versions tab and select a previous version

From within that version, there is an option to download the code

As suggested in the comments, use a framework like Serverless (https://www.serverless.com/) to handle your deployments properly, and signup for Github to maintain your source code.

I manage to recover the fields as I downloaded the code a few days before.
However, let this be a learning experience for newbies like me - It's not good idea to edit code directly in the AWS Lambda, and if you do, use versioning.
